# Unable to do pip install pandas-profiling

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, data-science, data-analysis

I've tried severally to install Pandas-Profiling on my windows 10 cmd using "pip install pandas-profiling" but it doesn't work. I've also tried installing it on conda but its the same story. I need help installing this please.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share what exactly you tried and what the error is that you receive, otherwise it is difficult to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. It didn't work with a normal `pip install`. I fixed it by running the following command in anaconda prompt:

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas-profiling
```

> You can find the full documentation [here](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/1.4.3/).

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't provide the error message, we can't help you.

If you have the following error message:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

It means that Python is not added to your Path environment variable. How to fix it:

1. First solution: Adding Python to the Path by going in your environment variables, in `System Variables` click on `Path` then `Edit`, and in the grid, add your Python's path (which may be `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python<version>\`). You can also add Python yo the Path by uninstall it and install it again and in the installer, make sure you check "Add Python to PATH"[image: Add Python to the Path in the installer]
2. Second solution: You can run pip by putting `python3 -m` before you pip command, like that: `python3 -m pip install pandas-profiling`.

Comment: The error message I got was “failed building wheel for astropy” and when I tried to install astropy, I got the same error message

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to find a solution to the error message. I had to install the Microsoft C++ Build Tools, then I launched it and did the installation through it using ‘pip install pandas-profiling’ you can download using the link https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Answer (score 0):

For me it only works also if putting "py"
so:
`py -m pip install pandas-profiling`

In the command prompt.